# Is this correct? Prove $5k+3$ is not divisible by $5$ using proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Let $n=5k$, $n$ and $k$ are integers. I will assume $n+3$ is divisible by $5$ which means there is an $m$ such that $n+3=5m$.

Now, $n+3-3=5m-3$, i.e. $n=5m-3$. 
We know that $n$ is divisible by $5$ so this can be $5k=5m-3$ therefore $3/5=(m-k)$, but this is a contradiction because $m$ and $k$ are integers.

Comment: Yes, but in the title, you should have mentioned that $n$ was a multiple of $5$ as well. (Also, I cleaned up the formulas; if you put \$'s around your math formulas, they look nicer.

Comment: It is fine. For no good reason, I would prefer to keep it in the integers, $3=5(m-kS)$. This is impossible, since $5$ does not divide $3$.

Comment: I echo the same point, but take it to the opposite conclusion: As you have it here, it is *not* correct because you assume something ($n$ is divisible by $5$) that is not given in the premises, and is not generally true. Carl Heckman and Andre Nicolas have been generous and assumed that it is a premise that you have failed to copy (i.e. the problem is "Prove that $5$ divides $n$ implies $5$ does not divide $n + 3$ by contradiction"). But I'm taking a more pendantic position to point out you need to be careful in communicating math. A small omission can be deadly.